# How to create database and asociate table with it in Mysql NODEJS

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am setting up mysql/nodejs app.

I would like to delete database, recreate it and create table on each server restart.

If I specify connection with database:

```js
let con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "pass",
  database: "my_db",
});
```

I can create table, indexes, insert values but just first time. Every subsequent time it will tell me that everything is already created.

If on the other hand I do not put database when I create connection, I can delete database, create new one, but when I try to create a table I get an error that I don't have a database associated with this table.

Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the database in the connection

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
      connectionLimit : 10,
      host            : 'example.org',
      user            : 'bobby',
      password        : 'pass'
    });
```

after that you can create the database

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    if(err){
        return cb(err);
    }
    connection.query("CREATE DATABASE mydb", function(err, data){
        connection.release();
        cb(err, data);
    });
});
```

and use

```
connection.changeUser({database : "mydb"});
```

to connect to the newly created database

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    if(err){
        return cb(err);
    }
    connection.changeUser({database : "mydb"});
  let createTodos = `create table if not exists mytable(
                          id int primary key auto_increment,
                          title varchar(255)not null,
                          testdata tinyint(1) not null default 0
                      )`;

  connection.query(createTodos, function(err, results, fields) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    };
});
```

This is split ito seperate function only to show the idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. Doing it manually.

   - If the user you are connected with is having all the privileges like a superuser, you can code it to drop database every time the server starts up (like in server.js or app.js depending upon your design) by executing the following.

   ```
   DROP {DATABASE | SCHEMA} [IF EXISTS] db_name;
   ```

   - PS: This is not something to be done in production environment so make sure you either remove it before final deployment or make it run as per env when env!=production.
2. Using a DB migration library for example -> https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting%20Started/commands/#dbdrop

   - DB dropping/recreating is not the primary use case of migration(migration = making changes to DB automatically when server boots), migration in itself is a process which is automated by these libraries.

Comment: But I can't code it up? Meaning I drop and create database with `con.query` and then once that is finished I create a table and somehow associate it with this database?

Comment: Right, you need to put it in that sequence where first the conditional dropping happens and later the creation, also check the updated answer.